# Apache Setup Error - .htaccess seems to not be working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ubuntu-16.04

Ok so today I got a new VPS server due to the fact a huge amount of domains were pointed to my old domain - I have no previous domains pointing to my new IP. I now have setup the server with ubuntu 16.04 - previous being Centos 7. I have tried everything to get .htacccess to work and my Virtual Hosts. Here below I have linked all the files!

```
.htaccess https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/25622957/
000-default.conf https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/25622958/
apache2.conf https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/25622964/
```

My question is what have I setup wrong here and the goal is I want to make sure if any domain is pointed to my Origin it will automatically rewrite to mydomain.com - I also want to have my Origin IP also either deny access or rewrite to the main site. I also am not sure how to check if my rewrites are even working as between different browsers different actions happen.

Comment: Have you enabled mod_rewrite?  It is not enabled by default in Ubuntu 16.04.  `sudo a2enmod rewrite` if you haven't already then `sudo service apache2 restart` for it to take effect.  Also, I personally prefer to limit my AllowOverride statements to the bare minimum that I need. If you only need to enable rewrite, `AllowOverride FileInfo` is all that is necessary.

Comment: Hi @blendenzo - I have already enabled at2nmod rewrite but I am unsure if any of its working - and can you use my code to explain your second point please.

Comment: @blendenzo - when you just say I need to AllowOverride FileInfo - I understand what you mean by just loading the one module, to limit the statements - but what is FileInfo declaring - where is that referencing?

Comment: The documentation on AllowOverride is here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/core.html#allowoverride If you're the only one maintaining and using the server, it doesn't really matter that much if you allow All or not.  I personally like to employ the principle of least privilege, so I don't grant permissions that aren't necessary.

Comment: Also, strangely enough, sometimes you need to clear your browser cache to see changes to your .htaccess files take effect. Especially if you're making changes on a remote server (not localhost).

Comment: @blendenzo I see, Is there anything wrong with my config files that would stop everything else working and I simply just change AllowOverride FileInfo and this is only going to reference mod_rewrite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I've used example.com in this answer, because mydomain is not allowed in posts on stackoverflow)

There are a few problems with your .htaccess file. First, look at this line:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^http://example.com$
```

You shouldn't included "http://" when you are testing the {HTTP_HOST}, so it should read like this instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.com$
```

Second, look at this line:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} !^https://example.com$
```

I have never seen anyone test for HTTPS like this before, and I cannot even find HTTPS_HOST in the [mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond).  I know of a multiple common methods to require HTTPS.  Here are a few of them, but you only need to use one:

```
# Methods of checking the port
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !80$  #True if traffic came in on HTTP port 80
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$  #True if traffic did not come in on HTTPS port 443

# Methods of checking the HTTPS status
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off  #True if HTTPS is off
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on  #True if HTTPS is not on
```

So taken all together, the following rewrite rule should do what you want:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: works really well man! - In this rewrite RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L] is the {REQUEST_URI} just stating to forward on the target location they were going for?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what {REQUEST_URI} does.  So if they tried to go to `http://example.com/about_us/` they would get forwarded to `https://example.com/about_us/`.  Worth noting: the rule above doesn't handle "www.example.com".  If you want it to catch that as well, change the first line to `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !(www\.)?example.com$` This will check for an optional "www."  (I might as well update the answer to include that)

Comment: In my cloudflare page rules - I have setup a rule that states any www.example.com will be redirected to https://example.com - But i guess this would then not carry over the {REQUEST_URI}